# AES custom key instead of 16, 24 or 32 bytes

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, secret-key

I am having problems with `keys AES` in Java

This is my code:

```
public Core(String key) {
    try {
        this.SecretKey = key;
        this.ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(this.iv.getBytes());
        this.keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        try {
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever I pass the String "key" that contains for example `Pizza`, it just generates errors. When I pass for example a String that contains precisely 16 bytes, it works. I would like to use AES, but I would not like it to only be limited to 16, 24 or 32 bytes. How can I fix this?

Comment: I was just asked by a crypto SME: "Why would you want to use non-standard key sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For AES with different key sizes (and different block sizes) look at Rijndael.  However, given your use of "Pizza" as a key, using Rijndael is probably too advanced for you.  Instead use a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (KDF) to turn your password ("Pizza") into a cryptographic key.  Have a look at `PBKDF2` if you are not sure what KDF to use.

I would also recommend using a passphrase instead of a password as input to your KDF: "*I like Ham and Pineapple Pizza.*"

ETA: Prefer `PKCS7` padding to NoPadding.  That way you will catch more errors in your code when the padding does not match.

Comment: [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html) is link that contains an android-specific code.

Comment: Padding should not be used to "catch errors", in fact reporting padding errors to the caller is a security error that allows a padding oracle attack.

Comment: AES has one block size: 128-bits and three key sizes: 128, 192 & 256 bits. Any other values of Rijndael are not AES.

Comment: @zaph - Given the apparent level of experience of the questioner, I was more intending to catch coding errors in the questioner's code.  Setting padding on is one way to flag up that there is an error in the questioner's code.  We see enough questions here with subtle, and not so subtle, errors in crypto coding.

Comment: The thing that padding errors "catch" is incorrect decryption, not actual padding errors and as such provide a misleading message. The other issue is that many inexperienced in encryption think they can rely on a padding error to determine if a correct key has been used and this fails > 1/256 and is incorrect usage. Some implementations stopped reporting padding errors to eliminate these two all-to-common usage errors. Finally, there is the Padding Oracle attack that can result by reporting padding errors back to the caller inadvertently.

Comment: Yes, and the "incorrect decryption" may be due to incorrect code from an inexperienced coder.

Comment: Right and you want to tell them there is a parity error when the error is going to be something else? Sorry, that is mis-direction. Not only does it not help the developer, it points then in the wrong direction. Nice–not.